# Reduce a table in R

Tags: r

I have a table that has a format along the lines of

```
user  data
1234  42
1234  51
1234  50
1235  61
1235  55
```

I want to create a histogram of the average "data" based on user.  In other words, I would like to combine rows of the table with the same `userID` and come up with an average for them. How would I do this on a large dataset?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, sorry, but this is rather weird question if one doesn't know where to start. Imagine a stranger walking your hometown asking for a way. Would you reply: "What have you tried?"??

Comment: @TomasT. I would expect even strangers would know to look at a map first before asking me. :) Seriously though, showing what you've tried is an [official](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) SO recommendation for questioners.

Comment: @TomasT. it's a completely legitimate question when my hometown is full of maps and resources to find your way.  This type of question has been answered hundreds of times on this site.  At least _try_ to find the answer by searching.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I had looked for terms around "mapping table data" which ended up not getting me very far. I found a couple of guides on R, but honestly I've found online documentation to be lacking and I haven't been able to find a great resource to help me do the things I want to do.

Comment: @ocoutts: I doubt you have a "table".  `help(table)` says a table class object is a contingency table.  You probably have a data.frame.  You're also not trying to "Map" or "Reduce" anything (see `help(Map)` and `help(Reduce)`).  You need to figure out the correct terminology before search results will be helpful.  Not trying to be rude, just trying to "teach to fish" rather than "give a fish".

Comment: @ocoutts: Most of us are self-taught. The canonical starting point is "introduction to R" which is part of the "online documentation" since it is included in every distributed copy of R. After that (several hours of self-study , working through the examples, and picking up basic R terminology) there is a huge amount of free more advanced "online documentation" at the CRAN website in the Documentation/Contributed link: http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html . Pick the one that matches your domain of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `tapply` (assuming that your original data frame is named `dat`):

```
avgdata=tapply(dat$data,dat$user,FUN=mean)
hist(avgdata)
```

Comment: Other options: `by` and the `plyr` package.

Comment: @gsk3: or `aggregate` which may be more intuitive than `tapply`.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_mean = tapply(data, user, mean)
hist(user_mean, breaks = 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's reproduce your data:

```
user <- c(rep("1234", 3), rep("1235", 2))
data <- c(42, 51, 50, 61, 55)
df   <- data.frame(user, data)
```

Now, for a one-line solution:

```
aggregate(data ~ user, df, mean)
```